# How to redirect a user after user_save?

Tags: php, drupal-7

I've have been trying to redirect the page after user_save in drupal 7. I have scenario in which a webform is used for registration process.when the users submits the webform ,it should be saved as a user in database and redirect to a 'test_page' .so i have tried

```
function custom_module_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission){
    $user=array(
        'name'=>$submission['data'][0]['value'];
        'pass'=>$submission['data'][1]['value'];
        'mail'=>$submission['data'][2]['value'];
    );
    user_save('',$user);
    drupal_goto('test_page');
}
```

After saving the user, the page is redirected to '/user' page instead of 'test_page'

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64171/redirect-user-to-their-profile-page-after-saving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use hook_form_alter();

with custom submit handler in custom module

```
function myCustomModule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == "user_register_form") {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'my_custom_register_submit';
  }
}

function my_custom_register_submit($form, &$form_state){
  $form_state['redirect'] = '/test_page';
}
```

hope this helps